# wrong boolean assignment - anagrams algorithm

Tags: java

I know that possibly you know better and faster ways, but excuse me - I'm learning...

My problem is that this method should ... but not with my present code...return the boolean "anagram" TRUE if all checked letters of particular words are present in examined word from second List...

my Boolean still gets the last checked letter state, please help.

```
for (String aWord : aWordsList){ //main List positions loop
                    tempWordsList = new ArrayList<String>(aWordsList);;

//set anagram TRUE if all letters of examined word found in temp List
                boolean anagram = true; 
                    for (int a=0; a<tempWordsList.size(); a++){ //temp List word loop
                    anagram = true;
                        for (int i=0; i<aWord.length(); i++){ //main List word Letters loop
                            anagram = true;
                            boolean letterFound = true;

                            for (int letter=0; letter < tempWordsList.get(a).length(); letter++){ //temp List word Letters loop

                                anagram = true;
                                String checkedTempWord = tempWordsList.get(a);
                                char checkedLetter = aWord.charAt(i);
                                char checkedTempLetter = tempWordsList.get(a).charAt(letter);

                                    if (aWord.charAt(i)==tempWordsList.get(a).charAt(letter)){
                                        letterFound = true;
                                        break;
                                        // OK, jump out and check next letter
                                    }else{
                                        letterFound= false;
                                    }

                            }
                            if (anagram == true && letterFound==true) {
                                anagram=true;
                            }else{
                                anagram=false;
                            }
                            System.out.println(aWord +" in "+ tempWordsList.get(a) + " : " + aWord.charAt(i) + " " + letterFound); 

                        }
                        System.out.println(aWord + " has anagram in " + tempWordsList.get(a) + ": " + anagram);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println(aWord + " " + tempWordsList + " " + anagram);
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. (Use an online formatter). Why do you have a second `;` on the second line? `tempWordsList = new ArrayList<String>(aWordsList);;`

Comment: I have found that I have to eliminate words that are different size

Comment: Are you supposed to be comparing the words in aWordsList to words in a different list?  tempWordsList = new ArrayList<String>(aWordsList) makes a new list with the same contents as aWordsList

Comment: yes, the part where I make it shorter is deleted above:
for (Iterator<String> iterator = tempWordsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
       String string = iterator.next();
       if (string.equals(aWord)) {
           // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
           iterator.remove();
       }

Comment: As written your code will always find at least one anagram for each word in aWordsList because the word itself qualifies.

Comment: I'm aware of this. it was added in my code before I pasted it here

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error: too many times anagram was set to true... 
this code looks working for me:

```
//set anagram TRUE if all letters of examined word found in temp List
            boolean anagram = true;
                for (int a=0; a<tempWordsList.size(); a++){ //temp List word loop
                anagram = true;
                    for (int i=0; i<aWord.length(); i++){ //main List word Letters loop
                        //anagram = true;
                        boolean letterFound = true;

                        for (int letter=0; letter < tempWordsList.get(a).length(); letter++){ //temp List word Letters loop

                            //anagram = true;
```